# How to create a user verification hash/token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So basically I have a registration endpoint in my express app. I am trying to make it so that users have to verify their email prior to their account being activated(the account is deactivated by default). I have everything set up, the only thing that is confusing me is how to create a hash that I can send as part of a link that a user clicks to verify their account. I have thought of using JWT and just creating a token and sending that along, however this seems a bit overkill. So my question is, is using JWT for this purpose a solid solution or is there a better alternative? If so, what is that alternative?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating hash/token from user email for email-verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747141/creating-hash-token-from-user-email-for-email-verification)

Comment: @Dropout I looked at that answer already. It uses the JWT solution that I was already thinking. I just wanna make sure there isn't a better way to do it.

Comment: how would you describe "better" and why avoid JWT? Does JWT lack something specific that you need?

Comment: Define "secure"--regardless of what's encoded (if anything) and how, it's still going to end up being something-sent-via-email with a mechanism for verifying on the back end, whether it's decoding or some form of GUID with a corresponding DB entry.

Comment: @Dropout yes, simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question can lead to opinionated answers and I will try to give you one.

If all you want to do is verify email, then JWT seems like an overkill to me. Just create a hash using `nanoid`, `shortid` package from npm or using standard nodejs `crypto`.

Save the hash to DB record of the user, send out the link as in

`https://my.server.com/whatever-path-you choose/${your-generated-hash}`

This should be handled by the server where the endpoint:

- looks up and verifies the user by the hash
- enables the account
- burns the hash (i.e. delete the hash from DB)
- redirects to the page of your liking, most probably login page.

My 2 cents.

Comment: JWT is definitely an overkill, very unnecessary in terms of complexity as well. Simply creating fairly secure hashes already does the job.

Comment: we should not save hash to DB to avoid data leak

Answer (score 0):

do a token that includes user id and a secret value to make it more safe but don't push your code online to hide this secret
also then put it as a cookie
another way without jwt is using res.locals